# Compute the sum of the red, green and blue channels using Python

Tags: python, image-processing

I have been taking an online course in Python and I came across a line of code that I am unable to explain. I am trying to compute the sum of the red, green and blue channels of an image and the line of code to do so is:

`img = plt.imread('480px-Astronaut-EVA.jpg')
intensity = img.sum(axis=2)`

Why is `axis=2` used to sum up the values of all the three channels? I am using the matplotlib library.

Comment: what is `img`? what library are you using?

Comment: @iamanigeeit Sorry for not bring clear. I have edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the original code that you are talking about. 
I assume it's :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Load the image into an array: img
img = plt.imread('myImage.jpg')

# Print the shape of the image
print(img.shape)  # Outputs : (480, 480, 3)
```

Then it calculates the sum of intensities over the third channel.

**Remember the axes are : 0, 1 and 2.**

```
# Compute the sum of the red, green and blue channels: intensity
intensity = img.sum(axis=2)
```

If you print the shape of the intensity :

```
# Print the shape of the intensity
print(intensity.shape)  # Output : (480, 480)
```

This means that for each couple of position (axe0_point, axe1_point), you sum the values of the axe 2.

For example, if `img[50,50] == [10,10,10]`, you'll have `intensity[50,50] = 30`

Answer (score 1):

axis=2 (third axis) directs to sum the color components:

```
B = image[:,:,0]; G = image[:,:,1]; R = image[:,:,2]
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imread.html):

> For RGB images, the return value is MxNx3.

This means the image is stored as an MxN array of pixels with each pixel having a 3-tuple (the R, G, B values). `img.sum(axis=2)` means add up the 3rd axis (the RGB values) for each pixel, returning a MxN array of intensity values.

Answer (score 0):

The image is read into from file into an numpy array. You can get the whole idea of axis and data manipulation by reading article [Numpy sum axis intuition](https://medium.com/@aerinykim/numpy-sum-axis-intuition-6eb94926a5d1) (especially the examples):

> The way to understand the “axis” of numpy sum is it collapses the specified axis. So when it collapses the axis 0 (row), it becomes just one row and column-wise sum.
>
> In 2-d arrays, it might be confusing, however when we talk about 3-d, 4-d, n-d, it’s the more straightforward way to define the axis.